# How to modify mysqli result? (adding one row to result)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmailer

I'm using phpMailer to send a Newsletter to an amount of users.
In a while-Loop i get the email adress of every single user:

```
$query = "...";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
... 
$mail->AddAddress($row['email']);
$newbody = str_replace("[NAME]",$row['name'],$body);
$mail->MsgHTML($newbody);

if(!$mail->send()) /* send Email */
{$_SESSION['logErrors'] .= $mail->ErrorInfo." (".$row['email'].")<br>";} else 
{$_SESSION['logSent'] .= $row['email']." - ".date("H:m:s")."<br>";}
$mail->ClearAddresses(); 
...
} // mysqli_fetch_assoc
} // mysqli_query
```

Now I would like to add an option like "send a copy of the Newsletter to me".
I think, the best way to do that would be adding one extra (virtual, temporary) row to this mysqli-result with my email in it.

So if i would check that option a if-statement would change my query and modify the result with a first new virtual row, containing my email-address.

Can anyone help me out with this? I have no Idea what the Query should look like.

```
MYSQL:                               MODIFIED RESULT:
| id | email | name | group |        | id | email    | name | group |  
|---------------------------|   -->  |------------------------------|
| 1  | foo@  | foo  | bar   |        | 1  | myemail@ | my   | my    |
| 2  | ..    | ..   | ..    |        | 2  | foo@     | foo  | bar   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. However, this is what your query may look like:

```
(select "1", "myemail", "my","my") union (<your_select_query>)
```

However, I would suggest, create a function that processes your data.
Call it once for your input and call it multiple times over the results of the query.

Comment: thats nice, i get a new first row but the col-names also change to "1", "myemail", "my" & "my". But they still shoul be "id", "name", "email" & "group".

Comment: i changed your code to: `(select "0" as id, "admin@admin.com" AS email, "my" AS name,"my" AS group) union (SELECT * FROM table_name)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to modify anything, if you send your newsletter in a loop, you can do it this way:

```
$query = "...";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     ... 
     $mail->AddAddress($row['email']);
     ...
   } // mysqli_fetch_assoc
   $mail->AddAddress('myemail@'); // here you add your email
} // mysqli_query
```

And to be honest, it's not the best way of sending newsletter. Now each person who get this email will see other emails e-mail address, so if one of your subscriber is your competitor, he will see all your clients/users messages. You should rather send emails separately or use `AddBCC` instead of `AddAddress`

**EDIT**

You could do in it the following way:

```
<?php

$query = "...";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    $rows = [];
    $record = [];
    $record['name'] = 'Your name';
    $record['email'] = 'Your email';
    $rows[] = $record;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        //...
        $mail->AddAddress($row['email']);
        $newbody = str_replace("[NAME]", $row['name'], $body);
        $mail->MsgHTML($newbody);

        if (!$mail->send()) /* send Email */ {
            $_SESSION['logErrors'] .= $mail->ErrorInfo . " (" . $row['email']
                . ")<br>";
        } else {
            $_SESSION['logSent'] .= $row['email'] . " - " . date("H:m:s")
                . "<br>";
        }
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        //...
    }


} // mysqli_query
```

So first, you get all results from database (and you add as first record your data), and then in loop you send email. It could be probably also done in other way, but not knowing what the rest code is, probably it's the best way.

Comment: after every while loop i use `$mail->ClearAddresses();`, AddBCC is not working with my sendmail

Comment: @user2987790 And where are you sending your emails? And what for are you using `ClearAddresses`? You have here one `while loop` not many, so I don't know what do you mean `after every while loop`.

Comment: Hey, i updated my code in the question - maybe i'm doing it the wrong way? I'm using clearAdresses() to clear the last email Adress within the loop - so every user get's his owne personal Email.

Comment: Thank you very much! i will try to adapt your code because i want to get best perfomance out of this newsletter script. I want to send about 400-500 emails. Is there a way to send emails in an interval of 20 Emails - then pause 3 seconds and restart the loop? Like: Email 0-20 / pause / Email 21 - 40 / pause /...